# Creating virtual screen for screen sharing

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, screen, zoom-meeting

I'm doing lectures via Zoom and I usually use one screen for my notes and a second screen for the presentation (I can also move slides from the screen with the notes). But since I don't really care about seeing the presentation, I want to create some kind of virtual screen that can be shared by Zoom and then use the new available screen for other things (mainly seeing the students' videos).

Is this possible to do in Ubuntu desktop?

Ubuntu 20.04 via xorg.